# Average of Columns by Unique ID in R

Tags: r

I would like to average columns in a data set based on a unique identifier. I do not know ahead of time how many columns I will have for each unique identifier or what order they will come in. The unique IDs are all known before hand and are lists of weeks. I have found solutions for regular patterns but not solutions for using the actual column headers to sort out the average. Thanks for any and all help.

I present the original data and desired result. In the example there are only 2 unique IDs

```
x = read.table(text = "
  site     wk1  wk2  wk1  wk1
    1       2    4    6    8
    2      10   20   30   40
    3       5   NA    2    3
    4     100  100   NA   NA", 
sep = "", header = TRUE)

x

desired.outcome = read.table(text = "
  site    wk1avg  wk2avg
    1      3.3      4
    2      26.6    20
    3      3.3     NA
    4       NA     100", 
sep = "", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: I believe you may need the `cast` function. Take a look at that.

Answer (score 3):

If your original data file has duplicated column names, `read.table` will change them so all the columns have unique values (as you can see by checking `x` in your example after it's loaded). In fact, the code below depends on that happening, because `melt` will drop columns with duplicated names. Then we use `mutate` to remove the extra text added by `read.table` to de-duplicate the column names so that we can group properly by week.

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)

x %>% melt(id.var="site") %>%   # Convert to long format
  mutate(variable = gsub("\\..*", "", variable)) %>%  # "re-duplicate" original column names
  group_by(site, variable) %>%     
  summarise(mn = mean(value)) %>%
  dcast(site ~ variable)

  site       wk1 wk2
1    1  5.333333   4
2    2 26.666667  20
3    3  3.333333  NA
4    4        NA 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyr` and `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

x %>% gather(wk, val, -site) %>%           # gather wk* columns into key-value pairs
    extract(wk, 'wk', '(wk\\d+).*?') %>%       # trim suffixes added by read.table
    group_by(site, wk) %>% 
    summarise(mean_val = mean(val)) %>%    # calculate grouped means
    spread(wk, mean_val)                   # spread back into wk* columns
# Source: local data frame [4 x 3]
# Groups: site [4]
# 
#    site       wk1   wk2
#   (int)     (dbl) (dbl)
# 1     1  5.333333     4
# 2     2 26.666667    20
# 3     3  3.333333    NA
# 4     4        NA   100
```